# In a function Bash: how to check if an argument is a set variable?

Tags: bash, variables, if-statement

I want to implement a bash function which test is the 1st argument is actually a variable, defined somewhere.

For instance, in my `.bashrc` :

```
customPrompt='yes';
syntaxOn='no';
[...]
function my_func {
    [...]
    # I want to test if the string $1 is the name of a variable defined up above
    # so something like: 
    if [[ $$1 == 'yes' ]];then 
         echo "$1 is set to yes";
    else
         echo "$1 is not set or != to yes";
    fi
    # but of course $$1 doesn't work
}
```

output needed :

```
$ my_func customPrompt
> customPrompt is set to yes
$ my_func syntaxOn
> syntaxOn is set but != to yes
$ my_func foobar
> foobar is not set
```

I tried a lot of test, like `-v "$1"`,  `-z "$1"`, `-n "$1"`, but all of them test $1 as a string not as a variable.
(please correct me if I make not myself clear enought)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the `bash` you can use the *indirect* variable subtituion.

```
t1=some
t2=yes
fufu() {
    case "${!1}" in
        yes) echo "$1: set to yes. Value: ${!1}";;
        '')  echo "$1: not set. Value: ${!1:-UNDEF}";;
        *)   echo "$1: set to something other than yes. Value: ${!1}";;
    esac
}

fufu t1
fufu t2
fufu t3
```

prints

```
t1: set to something other than yes. Value: some
t2: set to yes. Value: yes
t3: not set. Value: UNDEF
```

The `${!variablename}` in bash mean `indirect variable expansion`. Described in the e.g. https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html

Whrere:

> The basic form of parameter expansion is ${parameter}. The value of
>   parameter is substituted. The braces are required when parameter is a
>   positional parameter with more than one digit, or when parameter is
>   followed by a character that is not to be interpreted as part of its
>   name.
>
> If the first character of parameter is an exclamation point (!), a
>   level of variable indirection is introduced. Bash uses the value of
>   the variable formed from the rest of parameter as the name of the
>   variable; this variable is then expanded and that value is used in the
>   rest of the substitution, rather than the value of parameter itself.
>   This is known as indirect expansion. The exceptions to this are the
>   expansions of ${!prefix } and ${!name[@]} described below. The
>   exclamation point must immediately follow the left brace in order to
>   introduce indirection.

Also, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16131829/632407 how to modify in a function a value of the variable passed indirectly.

Comment: I like the approach, great works ! Could you edit your answer to explain a bit (with a link maybe) what `"${!VAR}"` is ? I understand how it works, because that's exactly what i was looking for, but I didnt find it. :)

Comment: @Ash_ added the basic bash link more you can find with "bash indirect variable expansion"

Comment: Perfect. Your other answer on the linked Q is really interesting too ! Thanks mate.

Comment: @Ash_ Enjoy, I'm glad to help. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can check variable set or not by simply like

```
if [[  $var ]]
then
    echo "Sorry First set variable"
else
    echo $var  
fi
```

You can do something like this for your script

```
customPrompt='yes';
syntaxOn='no';
function my_func 
{
      if [[ ${!1} ]];then 
          echo "$1 is set to ${!1}";
      else
         echo "$1 is not set";
      fi
}
my_func customPrompt
my_func syntaxOn
my_func foobar
```

Output:

```
customPrompt is set to yes
syntaxOn is set to no
foobar is not set
```

You can customize the function as per you requirement by simply making some comparison conditions.

For more details you can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874389/bash-test-for-a-variable-unset-using-a-function?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to check if your variable is set or unset (not just empty), use this format:

```
function my_func {
    if [[ -z ${!1+.} ]]; then 
         echo "$1 is not set."
    elif [[ ${!1} == yes ]]; then
         echo "$1 is set to yes"
    else
         echo "$1 is set to \"${!1}\"."
    fi
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have problems...

The Bash shell is a very wily creature. Before you execute anything, Bash comes in and interpolates your command. Your command or shell script never sees whether or not you have a variable as a parameter.

```
$ set -x
set -x
$ foo=bar
+ foo=bar
$ echo "$foo"
+ echo bar
bar
$ set +x
```

The `set -x` turns on *debugging mode* in the shell. It shows you what a command actually executes. For example, I set `foo=bar` and then do `echo $foo`. My `echo` command doesn't see `$foo`. Instead, before `echo` executes, it *interpolates* `$foo` with `bar`. All `echo` sees at this point is that it's suppose to take `bar` as its argument (not `$foo`).

This is awesomely powerful. It means that your program doesn't have to sit there and interpret the command line. If you typed `echo *.txt`, `echo` doesn't have to expand `*.txt` because the shell has already done the dirty work.

For example, here's a test shell script:

```
#! /bin/sh
if [[ $1 = "*" ]]
then
    echo "The first argument was '*'"
else
    "I was passed in $# parameters"
fi
```

Now, I'll run my shell script:

```
$ test.sh *
I was passed in 24 parameters
```

What? Wasn't the first parameter of my script a `*`? No. The shell grabbed `*` and expanded it to be all of the files and directories in my directory. My shell script never saw the `*`. However, I can do this:

```
$ test.sh '*'
The first argument was '*'
```

The single quotes tell the shell not to interpolate anything. (Double quotes prevent globbing, but still allow for environment variable expansion).

This if I wanted to see if my first parameter is a variable, I have to pass it in ***single*** quotes:

```
$ test.sh '$foo'
```

And, I can do this as a test:

```
if [[ $1 != ${1#$} ]]
then
    echo "The first parameter is the variable '$1'"
fi
```

The `${1#$}` looks a bit strange, but it's just `${var#pattern}`. This removes `pattern` from the left most side of `$var`. I am taking `$1` and removing the `$` if it exists. This gets expanded in the shell as:

```
if [[ $foo != foo ]]
```

which is true.

So, several things:

- First, you've got to stop the shell from interpolating your variable. That means you have to use single quotes around the name.
- You have to use pattern matching to verify that the first parameter starts with a `$`.
- Once you do that, you should be able to use your variable with `${$1}` in your script.